# LISTAGG is not working when another column is selected

Tags: sql, oracle

I have table `BATTERY` that contains 2 columns `BATTERY_PN` and `UNDOT_FILE_NAME` with following data.

```
BATTERY_PN     UNDOT_FILE_NAME

135259-0000    UNDOT_ API-700-008685-005 40GP.PDF
135259-0000    China Sea Cert API-700-008685-005 40GP.PDF
```

I want to concatenate `UNDOT_FILE_NAME` column separated by semicolon(;) into single row. I am trying this query but it's giving me an error that `ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expected`.

**My Query:**

```
SELECT 
BATTERY_PN,
LISTAGG(UNDOT_FILE_NAME, '; ') WITHIN GROUP(ORDER BY UNDOT_FILE_NAME) UNDOT_FILE_NAME
FROM BATTERY
GROUP BY BATTERY_PN
```

I don't understand the reason because I think my syntax is **OKAY**. When I remove `BATTERY_PN` column from `SELECT` statement and only choose `UNDOT_FILE_NAME` column, it works fine. Anyone can help in fixing this query ?

**Expected output:**

```
BATTERY_PN     UNDOT_FILE_NAME

135259-0000    UNDOT_ API-700-008685-005 40GP.PDF; China Sea Cert API-700-008685-005 40GP.PDF
```

Comment: Your query **is** OK, so it must be something with the *Oracle cloud infrastructure*, I guess. Which database version is it?

Comment: Not able to replicate(_in on-premise_). It is working for me in 11g and 18c. [Fiddle Link](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=96b021164b3cd07552bbc3ae8de409a1)

Comment: @Littlefoot it's 19c

Comment: I don't have 19c; apex.oracle.com runs 18c, I have 11g and 12c. Could it be a bug in version you use?

Comment: @Littlefoot that's what I believe as well. I should contact support center.

Comment: @DoonieDarkoo . . . Errors like this can occur if you mistyped a character in the query -- and such characters can be invisible.  I would be surprised if there were an error that affected such a simple query.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I triple checked my query word by word and found no such issue. I even created a sample database on 11g and ran the same query and it is working fine there. It's obvious this is sort of bug in Oracle Cloud's 20D version. I was also hoping if there is any alternative way to achieve the same output just to save time if they don't respond quickly.

Comment: @DoonieDarkoo . . . If you had included the information about the query working in other versions of Oracle, you probably would not have gotten "close" votes.

Answer (score 0):

When using quoted identifiers you want to use double quotation marks (") instead of single ('). More can be found on naming rules and qualifiers here - https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/sql_elements008.htm#SQLRF00223